Finding a Fyne menu item to enable/disable it
I have a Fyne app with a MainMenu and need to enable/disable menu items in response to events. For example, the "Save" menu option should only be enabled when the user is working with a file.
My approach is to have a single EnableDisableMenuItems() function and call it whenever application state that should result in menu changes happens.
Is there a 'right' way to find the Save menu item in my EnableDisableMenuItems() function? Should I keep a reference to it somewhere and use that reference? Iterate through all items in the menu until I find a matching label? Something else?

Yes, like all widgets where you might want to change their state later the best thing to do is retain a reference to it in some way.
It does not have to be in a global state but some function could be responsible for updating the menu and it is aware of the items that were created and can therefore update them.
